# How to manually set a value in Dropdown widget in AppMaker?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I'm using REST API as a datasource and not sure how to manually set a value in the Dropdown widget

The widget datasource is set to `Client` options are set to `@datasource.items`. The "display field" is `name`.

I'm running a script after the widget/data is loaded, I'm able to get all the options as an array and find the one that needs to be selected, but can't set the value to the widget.

What I tried is `widget.values = widget.options[<index>]` but it seems to always select the first option, no matter what the index is.

Comment: r u doing it on data load when are you assigning the value, for example  widget.value = 1,2 if number or widget.value = 'Student'

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting a `item` in the [datasource](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#DataSource):

```
widget.datasource.selectIndex(/*INDEX HERE*/);
```

Comment: still selects the first option anyway. I have `@datasource.item` in the value prop in Dropdown settings

Comment: weird because if I subscribe to the `onValueChange` event and `console.log(widget.datasource.itemIndex), it shows the correct index which I selected (manually)

Comment: @Hobroker May be `selectKey()` will work. But you need to know the key or retrieve it.